# Oracle-SQL with multiple where-conditions extremely slow

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, select

I've found a strange behaviour in my (Hibernate)SQL-query. I've multiple and/or statements in my query. If I split the query in three different queries, then the query is much faster even with the additional selects I have to do.

But what is the cause of that and how could I resolve that? I do only two select-statements so I think the problem is somewhere else.

Here my query:

```
Select * from zdadba.tpartner partner where
             partner.partnrext in (
                     select distinct stapel.fpartnrext from zdadba.tstapel stapel
                     where stapel.lagernd = 1
                     and stapel.auftrag_id is null and 

                 (
                     (
                         cast(stapel.version as date) <= to_date('30.06.' || to_char(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                     ) and
                     (
                         to_date(sysdate) >= to_date('30.06.' || to_char(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                     )
                        and
                     (
                        partner.versandart = 'Halbjaehrlich'
                     )                      
                 )
                or
                 (
                    (
                        cast(stapel.version as date) <= to_date('01.01.' || to_char(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                    ) and
                     (
                         to_date(sysdate) <= to_date('30.06.' || to_char(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                     )
                 )
                    and partner.versandart = 'Halbjaehrlich'
             or 
              (
                 (
                     (
                         cast(stapel.version as date) <= to_date('01.01.' || to_char(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                     ) and
                     (
                         to_date(sysdate) >=  to_date('01.01.' || to_char(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                     )
                 )  and partner.versandart = 'Jaehrlich'
              )
             );
```

Comment: Your 2nd "OR" condition... it looks like you accidentally left the "and partner.versandart" out, and it would be a logical flaw with the pattern of the others.  Also, with all the date conversions, what is it you are actually trying to do since some are >= others <= and the 3rd is for a different partner.

Comment: How much records do you have in your `stapel` table? What are your indexes in this table? What are your index types? You're using too many date conversion, comparison and extraction that each one impacts the overall performance of the query

Answer (score 1):

There are two constructs you are using that tend to be associated with slow response.  One is the use of subqueries (the target of the "in" operator).  The other is the OR operator.

You can often rewrite a query that uses IN with a subquery as an equivalent query with a JOIN.  The result is often faster.

You may have no choice but to use the OR operator.  Sometimes, you can come up with an alternative that uses UNION to combine result sets, but that often runs slow as well.